# C++ vector _mylast returned 0xC

Tags: c++, vector, shared-ptr

I have a vector, filled with `shared_ptr`s of a [SFML](https://www.sfml-dev.org/index.php) class (`sf::Drawable`). Now there is a function which takes a new `shared_ptr` of `sf::Drawable` and add it to the vector. The vector declaration (it is inside a class named `GUINodeBody`, don't get confused by the name):

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<sf::Drawable>>* allTestWidgets;
```

Now, the function:

```
void GUINodeBody::addWidget(std::shared_ptr<sf::Drawable> widget) {
    allTestWidgets->push_back(widget);
}
```

But when I call this function, Visual Studio throws a exception in `vector`, line 1731:

```
Reading acess violation
std::_Vector_alloc<std::_Vec_base_types<
    std::shared_ptr<sf::Drawable>,
    std::allocator<std::shared_ptr<sf::Drawable> >
> >::_Mylast**(...) returned 0xC.
```

Does anybody know why the exception could be thrown?

Comment: That's easy. The exception is thrown because there is a bug somewhere in your code. The bug can be anywhere. Just because the program crashes on this line doesn't mean that's where the bug is. For example, writing to an invalid pointer succeeds, but ends up corrupting memory. The program continues to run until it reaches something that tries to use the corrupted memory, and crashes. You will have to figure out where the bug is in your code, and fix it. If you can come up with an example that meets all requirements of a [mcve], as explained the [help], you can edit your question and include it.

Comment: Addressing the smoke before we get to the fire: why is `allTestWidgets` a pointer?

Comment: @Quentin I thought, this would be handier for pasing it to another class and so on

Comment: @Ben you can pass a pointer or a reference to your vector regardless of how you own it. If you want to transfer ownership of the contents, you can move it.

Answer (score 0):

Not having access to VS, with such a low address error I expect your `allTestWidgets` is a `nullptr`.

Easily demonstrated with the following snippet:

```
#include <vector>
std::vector<int>* allTestWidgets;

void addWidget(int widget)
{
    allTestWidgets->push_back(widget);
}

int main()
{
//  allTestWidgets = new std::vector<int>; This is the fix line
    addWidget(42);
    delete allTestWidgets;
}
```

Comment: This is a fair guess but still a guess, the violation could just as easily come from reading a garbage/null ptr to `GUINodeBody` or some other random bug we can't see. Also the "fix" will probably just leave the op with more problems.

Comment: This is true, and reading into `GUINodeBody` (not familiar with it) must involve assess during use of the `std::vector`-class. But other random bugs cannot be excluded of course.

Comment: Oops, sorry, I had somehow forgotten to initialize a vector. Thanks! (It works now)